# Producer-consumer architecture with Java RealTime

Tags: java, multithreading, real-time, producer-consumer

I am working on designing trade system using Java Realtime ( Sun JRTS 2.2 ) and would like to few questions about best practices, because I am afraid of inventing the wheel and pretty sure that my task was already solved.

So I have thread that continuously reading the socket, parsing bytes and extracting messages (binary protocol ). Afterwards, I should send messages to the algorithm, that actually does some calculation and make decision to trade or not.

So I think the way I should design this system is to split it into 2 parts. Producer ( periodic(?) Realtime thread that extracts bytes from socket, parse it ) and Consumer ( Realtime thread (periodic/sporadic?) that extracts messages from producer, manipulates with them etc ).

So the first question is how to design high performance communication between these 2 threads ( producer/consumer )? Also I would love to hear the comments about the existing experience in designing such systems, advices and etc.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are aware that Realtime does not necessarily mean faster?

Comment: yes, I do. But I should also aware of garbage collector, high frequency and low latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with a similar problem but in a different domain:

Here is how I dealt with that:

```
public class Producer extends Thread{
   private BlockingQueue<E> consumerQueue = null;
   public setConsumerQueue(BlockingQueue<E> val){
      consumerQueue = val;
   }
   // main method where data is received from socket...
   public void run(){
      while(!interrupted()){
           data = socket.receive();// Receive data
           if(consumerQueue!=null) consumerQueue.offer(data);
      }
   }
}

public class Consumer extends Thread{
   private BlockingQueue<E> consumerQueue = new BlockingQueue<E>();
   public Consumer (Producer val){
      val.setConsumerQueue(consumerQueue);
   }
   public void run(){
      while(!interrupted()){
           data = consumerQueue.take();// block until there is data from producer
           if(data !=null) processData(data);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think we need to look at disrupt library and make thread communication latency much lower.

Comment: Depends on the amplitude of latency your application can take but if you want things to go faster (real time) then I am afraid you have to go for a faster native language such as C++

Answer (score 0):

When deciding how to break up your application it is useful to have a good idea of how long each stage takes and what processing can be done in parallel. You want to time each stage in micro-seconds and have measure the distribution.  The most interesting points are usually the 99% (worst 1%), 99.9% or 99.99%tile latencies.

---

I would have a look at the [disruptor](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/) library. This is a fairly general purpose library designed for high throughput and low latency.

---

If you want something simpler there is a number of patterns which can exchange data between threads in sub-microsecond time, however these are point solutions which depend on your specific use case.

You might find this presentation interesting, though it mostly deals with testing low latency, high throughput components and communication over sockets.  http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/11/low-latency-slides.html

Comment: Peter, thank you for your disrupt library recommendation. This is definitely one of the things i should take on consideration. Maybe you can recommend some techniques/patterns for dealing with high performance/low latency reading from socket ( i developed simple prototype with Java NIO but i am pretty sure there is some aspects to tune ).

Comment: I suggest you tune your system like I did in the presentation. (Allocated thread to cores using affinity) Use busy waiting to lower latency further.  If you can, use a kernel bypass network adapter. e.g. Solarflare or Myricom. Try using `rdtsc` directly to reduce the cost of using timestamps.

Comment: BTW: If you are using busy wait a simple queue to use is AtomicReference ;)

Comment: BTW2: You might find this puzzle interesting http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/11/java-puzzle-low-latency-queue.html

Comment: Thank you for links,Peter, subscribed to your blog :)

Comment: Could you also recommend some patterns for performance testing?

Comment: I would suggest a throughput test; send realistic messages as fast as you can for 10 seconds and take an average rate. and a latency test; send messages with a timestamp e.g. System.nanoTime() for 10 seconds and record each latency on the receiver (assuming its the same system) sort the results and look at the typical (middle) latency, 99% and 99.9% or 99.99%tile.