# how do I make a socket manager for a Swing GUI?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, try-with-resources, utility-method

Right now I have a console client which communicates with the server via `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` and `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`.  For a console based application, this seems to work as is.

The problem is that the class which has the i/o streams **also** has a reference to the `System.console()` object!

How can I refactor this class so that it's more generalized?  I would almost want to treat the connection as a utility, or, perhaps, as a bean, which would then get passed **to**, for example, a Swing GUI, or, perhaps, a system console.

```
package net.bounceme.dur.client;

import net.bounceme.dur.data.Title;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.data.State;

public class Client {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());
    private String server = "localhost";
    private int portNumber = 8080;
    private final Console c = System.console();

    private Client() {
    }

    public Client(String server, int portNumber) {
        this.server = server;
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
    }

    public void inputOutput() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Socket socket = new Socket(server, portNumber);
        boolean eof = false;
        Title title = null;
        State state = State.undefined;
        try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
            do {
                try {
                    title = (Title) objectInputStream.readObject();
                    log.info(title.toString());
                    do {
                        state = State.undefined;
                        try {
                            c.printf("enter the state for record:");
                            state = State.valueOf(c.readLine());
                        } catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                            log.warning(Arrays.deepToString(State.values()));
                        }
                    } while (state == State.undefined);
                    title.setState(state);
                    title.setTitle("modified from client");
                    objectOutputStream.writeObject(title);
                } catch (java.io.EOFException eofe) {
                    eof = true;
                }
            } while (!eof);
        }
    }

}
```

see also:

[Java - Sockets and Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573482/java-sockets-and-swing)

Comment: Do some reading on the [Producer/Consumer](http://java.dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern) pattern.  Instead of writing to the `Console`, you should be either raising events or writing the content to some kind of queue that can be read by interested parties, for example

Comment: You might also consider doing some reserch in to the concept of programming to an interface, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for the Code Review Stack Exchange site.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8301236/262852